# Getting audio's peak values using NAudio

Tags: vb.net, audio, naudio, meter

I use the following [Visual Basic .NET] code to play an audio file:

```
Dim waveoutdevice As NAudio.Wave.IWavePlayer = New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut
Dim mainoutputstream As NAudio.Wave.WaveStream
Dim volumestream As NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32mainoutputstream = CreateInputStream("C:\music\song.mp3")
waveoutdevice.Init(mainoutputstream)
waveoutdevice.Play()
```

That works.
But I don't know how to make a volume peak meter.
I've searched all over the internet but I can't find anything useful for me.
Can somebody please help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several peak meter examples in the NAudio demo code. For example [AudioPlaybackPanel](https://naudio.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NAudioDemo/AudioPlaybackDemo/AudioPlaybackPanel.cs) uses a `MeteringSampleProvider` to generate the peaks to pass to a peak meter control. If you have access to PluralSight, there is a module in my [NAudio course](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/audio-programming-naudio) that explains in more detail how this code works.